# kronecker delta function operator times sequences

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

can somebody help me the simplified form of 
$$M(i,j)=a_{i,j}\sum_{k}b_k\delta_{ik}\delta_{jk}$$ 
is?
where M is a matrix with elements M(i,j), $a_{i,j}$ is just some function of i and j, $b_k$ is a sequence and $\delta$ is Kronecker delta function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the cases of $i = j$ and $i \neq j$ separately. You should find that $M(i,j) = 0$ whenever $i \neq j$.